# Where in the Sabre API can I find commissionable rates on premium air travel (first and business) and hotels?

Tags: sabre

I'm looking to better understand what travel agents can earn on the products and services they sell, excluding fees.

Comment: What does their documentation say?

Comment: This seems more like a Business question that you should engage Sabre Sales and Biz Development teams, independent of technical implementation.

Comment: I looked through their documentation but couldn't find anything that spoke to  commissionable rates.

Answer (score 0):

Airline commissions are almost never listed in any air pricing responses from carriers; they are mostly negotiated between the carriers and the TMCs privately (when they exist at all). Looking for that kind of info using a Sabre API is likely not going to work.

Hotel commissions are generally 10% unless otherwise listed in the pricing response as Non-Commissionable. In my experience, each hotel chain can return different verbiage about Commissionable vs. Non-Commissionable hotels in their pricing responses.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I'm aware that broadly speaking airlines do not offer a commission unless separately negotiated, but wondering if that holds true for business and first travel as well.